# Замена файла в assets

Tags: android

Есть приложение. Внутри него лежит текстовик, в папке assets; из него берутся данные. Как известно, ресурсы в этой папке никак не упаковываются. Вопрос: могу ли я используя обычный WinRAR в любой нужный момент открыть это приложение и заменить этот текстовик? Ничего не повредится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinRAR'ом открыть приложение не получится. WinRAR'ом можно открыть .apk и вытащить ресурсы. Обратно их упаковать так, чтобы сертификат подписи остался такой же нельзя.